# Maximum flow in integer flow network

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, network-flow, dag

Let's say you have a maximum integer flow function in a network with 7 **directed** edges, meaning the flow cannot be increased anymore. The capacity of each edge is then increased by one. The capacity of all edges is always an integer, and so is the flow. Is there an algorithm that can find a maximum flow in this new network with complexity O(|E|), where E is the set of edges? If so, what would this algorithm look like?

Comment: Is the **7** an accident in this question?  Or does your graph really have only 7 edges?  The question is interesting (but with answer _not as far as we know_) if you simply drop **7** from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have $7$ edges (and hence at most $8$ vertices reachable from the flow source) any flow algorithm whose runtime is independent of the edge weights will take time $O(1) = O(|E|)$.
See, for example, the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: Why are there at most 8 vertices reachable from the flow source?

Comment: Consider the undirected version of your input network. The number of edges in this network is at most $7$ by hypothesis. Consider the connected component $C$ containing the source. Pick any spanning tree $T$ of $C$. The number of edges in the tree is a lower bound to the number of edges in $C$. A tree with $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges.  Therefore if $C$ has $9$ or more vertices, then $T$ has 8 edges, and both $C$ and the input network contain at least $8$ edges.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the edges are directed. I have edited the question. Since it is not given that the graph is connected, can we still use the same reasoning?

Comment: My answer (and my previous comment) works regardless of whether the graph is directed or undirected. Also, I never assumed that the graph was connected.

Comment: Then how can we assume that there exists a component $C$ in a graph that is not connected?

Comment: Every vertex of an undirected graph belongs to exactly one connected component.

Comment: And in that case, why would the complexity of the algorithm be $O(1)$?

Comment: Restrict yourself to the connected component containing the source. This can be done in linear time in the number of edges, i.e., a constant since there are at most $7$ edges. The algorithm that I linked takes time $O(n^2 m)$, i.e.,  at most $c n^2m$ for some constant $c$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges). We know that $n \le 8$ and $m \le 7$. Therefore the overall time spent is at most $448c$, i.e., a constant. All constants are in $O(1)$, by definition of big-Oh.

Answer (score 1):

In case the **7** was entered accidentally, and the question was whether a max flow can be computed in time $O(m)$ provided that we have a max flow already, and simply increase all capacities by one.

The answer is that the best max flow algorithm is $\omega(m)$ for graphs of unit capacities, which means that if you start out with only capacity $0$ for your graph, the empty flow $f \colon e \mapsto 0$ is a max flow.  Then if you increase all capacities with 1, you have a unit capacity flow network.  An algorithm with time $O(m)$ would be a ground-breaking achievement at this time (but still possible).